# Uploading Picture to page album is working But posting a picture on wall is not

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Error am getting** OAuthException: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted

I have got a very strange problem,I am able to upload pictures on my page album using graph api,but when i try to post a picture using graph api,it is not working,

**Note** when i post a message or a link to wall,its getting posted,the problem is only with the picture.

Here i am putting both the code snippets:

1,This is when i am trying to upload a picture to page album(working):

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://apps.facebook.com/pagecron");
$x=realpath($_FILES['source']['tmp_name']);
$parameters = array('message' => $_POST['message'],'source' =>'@' . $x );
$parameters['access_token'] = $_SESSION['active']['access_token'];
$check=$facebook->api('/'.$_SESSION['active']['id'].'/photos/','POST',$parameters);
```

2,This is when i am trying to post a picture to the wall(Not Working):

```
$img = realpath($y);
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://apps.facebook.com/pagecron");
$x=realpath($_FILES['source']['tmp_name']);
$parameters = array('message' => $_POST['message'],'picture' =>'@' . $x );
$parameters['access_token'] = $_SESSION['active']['access_token'];
$check=$facebook->api('/'.$_SESSION['active']['id'].'/feed/','POST',$parameters);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @phwd no error at all..infact everything goes smooth,its just that nothing is getting posted(inacase of wall posting)...incase of album upload ,picture is getting uploaded and infact appears to the wall also but as a combination of 5 6 pictures (added a new photo).Not as a single picture.

Comment: Check the `$check` variable and your error log. If it goes smooth you will get the post id.

Comment: @phwd it says OAuthException: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ist Thing**: You need to POST to `/TIMELINE_PHOTOS_ALBUM_ID/photos`.

**2nd Thing**:There may not be an album with such a name,so you should ist create it(After checking).

**How To**:

```
 $albums =$facebook->api('pageid/albums',GET,array('access_token'=>'access_token');      
 foreach($albums['data'] as $album)
 {
   if($album['name'] == 'TIMELINE_PHOTOS')
   {
      $uid = $album['id'];
   }
 }
if(isset($uid) && $uid !=0)
{
  //mean album is there so use that uid to post your photo
}
else 
{
    //create your album with that name and use its id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that if you want to post a photo to a user's wall, you need to `POST` to `/TIMELINE_PHOTOS_ALBUM_ID/photos`.

There doesn't appear to be a shortcut here to get at this. You need to search through the results of `/USER_ID/albums` to find the `album_id` of album named "Timeline Photos" (or get it using FQL).

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) says that albums have a limit of 200 photos. I'm not sure what happens if a user has more than 200 photos in their "Timeline Photos" album. I couldn't find a friend to inspect this against.

Comment: Well this is something came to mah mind too,but as you see my app has already created a album to upload pictures at,when u upload a picture,instead of showing that single picture to wall,it shows a bunch of 4 5 pictures of that album.i want to simply post a picture as a single picture.

Comment: There is no way to control how Facebook "rolls up" actions on a user's wall.

Comment: but people do photo posting,i have heard that.although i am not sure if its possible on pages too.

Comment: The difference is that you are trying to post to the album you created, instead of posting to the timeline album. Try posting to the timeline album instead. The difficulty you get here is that the timeline album for a user won't necessarily exist, if they have never posted any pics themselves, so don't assume its already there.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers And what if 200 picture limit has already reached to the timeline album??

Comment: Test it out and tell us what you find!

To be honest though I don't think its enforced. I have seen galleries bigger than that.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers yup its working great now with that timeline album thing.The only problem i am getting is with my schdelar,its schdeules the picture properly,but shows app error at last.(although its doing what i want it to)